# Wordpress is_page_template query

Tags: wordpress

i use a Plug-in on my wordpress site which uses a query to show search results, thats the code of the query:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
?>
<?php echo $query->found_posts; ?> Ergebnisse gefunden<br />
<?php
while ($query->have_posts())
{
    $query->the_post();

    ?>
    <div>
        <?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo '<p>'; the_post_thumbnail("small");   echo '</p>'; } ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    </div>


    <?php
}
?>
Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?><br />
<a href="#" class="pagi-prev">Previous</a> | <a href="#" class="pagi-next">Next</a>
<?php
}
else
{
echo "No Results Found";
}
```

The search should only display results from pages who uses a specific page template (mytemplate.php)

I found the Docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template who explain this, but i dont get it to work inside the above query.

any help would be nice :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Please do as below.

```
if ( is_page_template( '{enter the name of page template with extension}' ) ) {
    // Enter your if code here 
} else {
    // Enter your else code here.
}
```

For this code to work you must select the page template option while creating the page in WordPress Admin Interface.

Comment: I set the right template in the page options but the result is always "No Results Found".